# Problem with loading image in JavaFX in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have a Maven project in InteliJ Idea IDE and I can't load an image even though it's in the resources folder. I just get a blank window and "Image loading error? true". Any ideas?

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    Image img = new Image("file:pawn.png");
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);

    System.out.println("Image loading error? " + img.isError());
    sp.getChildren().add(imgView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the image is part of your application, don't use a `file:` protocol (it won't be a file when the application is, e.g., bundled as a jar). Assuming this is following a standard Maven-type build, the url should be just `"/pawn.png"`, or, more explicitly, `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/pawn.png").toExternalForm()`.

Comment: If you need to troubleshoot further, you need to check the build folder (`target/classes`). What's present in the source folders is basically irrelevant to what happens at runtime.

Comment: @James_D That "/pawn.png" did resolve my problem.

Comment: It looks like a Maven project structure where the resource folder is not structured correctly.  Just my guess.